# CentOS 8 compiling kernel 5.13.7 BTF Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos8, rhel8

I'm compiling Kernel 5.13.7 for Centos 8.4.2105

I've got the below error

```
  MODPOST vmlinux.symvers
  MODINFO modules.builtin.modinfo
  GEN     modules.builtin
BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole (pahole) is not available
Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux
Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
make: *** [Makefile:1205: vmlinux] Error 1
```

I tried searching on Google and got this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657707/btf-tmp-vmlinux-btf-pahole-pahole-is-not-available

But that is only for debian/fedora/OpenSuse

Can someone please help me regarding Centos 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the CentOS PowerTools repository, then you can install `dwarves`.